# header and primary menu covering content how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, css, menu, header

I know there are many answers here. Yet I asked the question again because I am not a developer. I make a website with simple drugs and drops. I don't know CSS. I'm in trouble. Content is covering because of the header and primary menu on my website. Someone help how to fix. This is only happening in the computer version. All is well in the mobile version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it´s very difficult help without information or impossible.
You need know a litte about CSS to identify the problem or compelte your post.